# RegEx and str_replace, modify a string by an other string in PHP from a text

Tags: php, regex, string, function, str-replace

I want to transform a certain number of characters by a string in PHP from a text :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fringilla
>   tincidunt justo sed hendrerit. Vivamus **[im::17,I]** elit id accumsan
>   pulvinar. Fusce ac lacus arcu. Nullam imperdiet imperdiet eros,
>   **[im::31,R]** congue libero. Aliquam non bibendum nisi. Nunc pretium feugiat nunc ut volutpat. Maecenas finibus viverra justo, quis luctus
>   **[im::11,L]** facilisis vel.

So what I try to do is to replace this :

```
[im::31,R]
```

By this:

```
<img src='img_31_0px.jpg' style='text-align:right;'/>
```

I got an array for the style inherit, left, right, center, this is not my difficulty.

This is my actual function:

```
function showimg($txtimg) {
        $fullstr = str_replace("[im::17,I]", "<img src='img_17_0px.jpg' style='text-align:inherit;'/>", $txtimg);
        return ($fullstr);
    }
```

As you can see, it's static for the moment, and not dynamic. I am looking on http://www.regexr.com/ to try something but it doesn't leed me anywhere.

Can you guys help me with my case, or leed me in the good direction at least?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to keep the alignment you'll need a callback:

```
function showimg($m) {
    $dir = array('I'=>'inherit','R'=>'right','L'=>'left');
    return '<img src="img_'.$m[1].'_0px.jpg" style="text-align:'.$dir[$m[2]].';"/>';
}

$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[im::([0-9]+),(I|R|L)\]/', 'showimg', $txtimg);
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally use your solution ! Thanks to MAchavity to for the participation

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that numbers will be 1 or 2 digits for this. I have the regex capture that tag and replace the digits found within

```
preg_replace('/\[im::(\d{1,2}),\w\]/', '<img src="img_\\1_0px.jpg" style="text-align:inherit;"/>', $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/W0LuZ

Answer (score 1):

This is how i far I got:

```
function showimg($txtimg) {
        $fullstr = str_replace("[im::", "<img src='img_", $txtimg);
        $fullstr = str_replace(",I]", "_0px.jpg' style='max-width:100%; text-align:inherit;'/>", $fullstr);

        return ($fullstr);
    }
```

I finaly used the answer of **AbraCadaver**